# touchesBegan() not being called on subviews

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a class called `SKButton`, subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, which implements the `touchesBegan()` function to `print("hello")`. But when i add an `SKButton` object to my view, `touchesBegan()` never gets called on the button. Why?

Comment: You need to make sure that userInteractionEnabled is enabled on all of the superviews of your view. Please verify it once

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Mysteriously, I had to set the `SKButton`'s `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true` manually, and that solved the problem. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that userInteractionEnabled is enabled on all of the superviews of your view.

Comment: I actually had to set `userInteractionEnabled` to true on the SKButton itself

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` is now `isUserInteractionEnabled`

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that coming from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 in your project might trigger the warning for the name of the method, you update it using the default fix and then you end up like me wondering why the methods related to touches are not called despite of the fact that you set userInteractionEnabled. Fix: make sure that method name is written as per your current version of Swift!